# $pull function of Waterline ODM for updating Mongo database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

Sails' Waterline lets you declare an attribute of an entity as being of type 'array':

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    stuff: { type: 'array' }
  }  
}
```

In mongodb there is the $pull operator which can be used in update queries and lets you remove certain values out of array attributes in multiple documents in a single query. From what I've searched I did not find anything which would enable this in Waterline, has anyone found a solution to this or a similar problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, so I did not find an aswer so what I did was to call a native mongo query. 
Resource.native(function (err, collection)) {
  // do native stuff with collection
}

This is not ok as now I am locked to mongodb for this functionality, but on the other hand I wouldn't know if the $pull feature mimed in sql type databases would have been ok or efficient.

Comment: You should show what you actually did as an answer so others might find it and learn when they face a similar problem.

Comment: Yes, I think I will do just that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I handled the problem. It is ok now as I am locked to mongodb anyway from various other db calls. Suppose I have the 'Entity' database model and the array attribute is 'arr'. The connection for the model must necessarily be to mongodb:

```
Entity.native(function (err, collection) {
  //handle err
  collection.update(objectsToUpdate, {
    $pull: { arr: myValue }
  }, function (err, result) {
    //do callback, etc.
  });
});
```